# Ruby - rspec tests fail (method not defined) but pass on local IDE

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've written some simple methods in ruby (not rails) and have tested them using regular rspec. They all pass on my system, but two of them fail in the course autograder AND if I run them on cloud9. How can that be? I've searched for any special issues with rspec on Windows, but there aren't any since at least ver 3.2.(I'm using 3.8)

Here's the output within my IDE:

```
    $ rspec

Ruby intro part 1
  #sum
    should be defined
    returns correct sum [20 points]
    works on the empty array [10 points]
  #max_2_sum
    should be defined
    returns the correct sum [7 points]
    works even if 2 largest values are the same [3 points]
    returns zero if array is empty [10 points]
    returns value of the element if just one element [10 points]
  #sum_to_n
    should be defined
    returns true when any two elements sum to the second argument [30 points]
    returns false for any single element array [5 points]
    returns false for an empty array [5 points]

#hello
  should be defined
  The hello method returns the correct string [30 points]

#starts_with_consonant?
  should be defined
  classifies true cases [10 points]
  classifies false cases [10 points]
  works on the empty string [5 points]
  works on nonletters [5 points]

#binary_multiple_of_4?
  should be defined
  classifies valid binary numbers [30 points]
  rejects invalid binary numbers [10 points]

BookInStock
  should be defined
  getters and setters
    should set ISBN [10 points]
    should set price [10 points]
    should be able to change ISBN [10 points]
    should be able to change price [10 points]
  constructor
    should reject invalid ISBN number [10 points]
    should reject zero price [10 points]
    should reject negative price [10 points]
  #price_as_string
    should be defined
    should display 33.95 as "$33.95" [10 points]
    should display 1.1 as $1.10 [10 points]
    should display 20 as $20.00 [10 points]

Finished in 0.03195 seconds (files took 0.30126 seconds to load)
34 examples, 0 failures
```

Now from the grader...

```
Ruby intro part 1
  #sum
    should be defined
    returns correct sum [20 points]
    works on the empty array [10 points]
  #max_2_sum
    should be defined (FAILED - 1)
    returns the correct sum [7 points] (FAILED - 2)
    works even if 2 largest values are the same [3 points] (FAILED - 3)
    returns zero if array is empty [10 points] (FAILED - 4)
    returns value of the element if just one element [10 points] (FAILED - 5)
  #sum_to_n
    should be defined
    returns true when any two elements sum to the second argument [30 points]
    returns false for the single element array [5 points]
    returns false for the empty array [5 points]

Failures:

  1) Ruby intro part 1 #max_2_sum should be defined
     Failure/Error: expect { max_2_sum([1,2,3]) }.not_to raise_error

       expected no Exception, got # with backtrace:

  2) Ruby intro part 1 #max_2_sum returns the correct sum [7 points]
     Failure/Error: raise 'NonInteger' if arr.all?(Integer) == false

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

  3) Ruby intro part 1 #max_2_sum works even if 2 largest values are the same [3 points]
     Failure/Error: raise 'NonInteger' if arr.all?(Integer) == false

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

  4) Ruby intro part 1 #max_2_sum returns zero if array is empty [10 points]
     Failure/Error: raise 'NonInteger' if arr.all?(Integer) == false

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

  5) Ruby intro part 1 #max_2_sum returns value of the element if just one element [10 points]
     Failure/Error: raise 'NonInteger' if arr.all?(Integer) == false

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Finished in 0.01805 seconds (files took 11744 minutes 10 seconds to load)
12 examples, 5 failures

Failed examples:

rspec your_code.rb:157 # Ruby intro part 1 #max_2_sum should be defined
rspec your_code.rb:160 # Ruby intro part 1 #max_2_sum returns the correct sum [7 points]
rspec your_code.rb:164 # Ruby intro part 1 #max_2_sum works even if 2 largest values are the same [3 points]
rspec your_code.rb:167 # Ruby intro part 1 #max_2_sum returns zero if array is empty [10 points]
rspec your_code.rb:170 # Ruby intro part 1 #max_2_sum returns value of the element if just one element [10 points]

BookInStock
  should be defined
  getters and setters
    should set ISBN [10 points]
    should set price [10 points]
    should be able to change ISBN [10 points]
    should be able to change price [10 points]
  constructor
    should reject invalid ISBN number [10 points]
    should reject zero price [10 points]
    should reject negative price [10 points]
  #price_as_string
    should be defined
    should display 33.95 as "$33.95" [10 points]
    should display 1.1 as $1.10 [10 points]
    should display 20 as $20.00 [10 points]

Finished in 0.00328 seconds (files took 11744 minutes 10 seconds to load)
12 examples, 0 failures

#hello
  should be defined
  The hello method returns the correct string [30 points]

#starts_with_consonant?
  should be defined
  classifies true cases [10 points]
  classifies false cases [10 points]
  works on the empty string [5 points]
  works on nonletters [5 points]

#binary_multiple_of_4?
  should be defined (FAILED - 1)
  classifies valid binary numbers [30 points] (FAILED - 2)
  rejects invalid binary numbers [10 points] (FAILED - 3)

Failures:

  1) #binary_multiple_of_4? should be defined
     Failure/Error: expect { binary_multiple_of_4?("yes") }.not_to raise_error()#::NoMethodError)

       expected no Exception, got # with backtrace:

  2) #binary_multiple_of_4? classifies valid binary numbers [30 points]
     Failure/Error: return false unless s.chars.all?(/[01]/) #

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

  3) #binary_multiple_of_4? rejects invalid binary numbers [10 points]
     Failure/Error: return false unless s.chars.all?(/[01]/) #

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Finished in 0.00239 seconds (files took 11744 minutes 10 seconds to load)
10 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec your_code.rb:175 # #binary_multiple_of_4? should be defined
rspec your_code.rb:178 # #binary_multiple_of_4? classifies valid binary numbers [30 points]
rspec your_code.rb:186 # #binary_multiple_of_4? rejects invalid binary numbers [10 points]
```

Edit:

Here are the passing/failing methods:

```
def max_2_sum(arr)

  # takes an array of integers as an argument and returns the sum of its two largest elements. 
  # For an empty array it should return zero. For an array with just one element, it should return that element.

  raise 'NonInteger' if arr.all?(Integer) == false
  return 0 if arr.empty?
  return arr[0] if arr.length == 1
  return sum(arr) if arr.length == 2
  arr.sort!
  sum(arr[-2..-1])

end

def binary_multiple_of_4?(s) 

  if s.length == 1
    return true if s == '0'
    return false if s == '1'
  else
    return false unless s.chars.all?(/[01]/)
    s[-1] == '0' && s[-2] == '0'
  end

end
```

Here are the tests:

```
  describe '#max_2_sum' do
    it 'should be defined' do
      expect { max_2_sum([1, 2, 3]) }.not_to raise_error
    end
    it 'returns the correct sum [7 points]', points: 7 do
      expect(max_2_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])).to be_a_kind_of Integer
      expect(max_2_sum([1, -2, -3, -4, -5])).to eq(-1)
    end
    it 'works even if 2 largest values are the same [3 points]', points: 3 do
      expect(max_2_sum([1, 2, 3, 3])).to eq(6)
    end
    it 'returns zero if array is empty [10 points]', points: 10 do
      expect(max_2_sum([])).to be_zero
    end
    it 'returns value of the element if just one element [10 points]', points: 10 do
      expect(max_2_sum([3])).to eq(3)
    end
  end

describe '#binary_multiple_of_4?' do
  it 'should be defined' do
    expect { binary_multiple_of_4?('yes') }.not_to raise_error#::NoMethodError)
  end
  it 'classifies valid binary numbers [30 points]' , points: 30 do
    %w[1010101010100 0101010101010100 100 0].each do |string|
      expect(binary_multiple_of_4?(string)).to be_truthy,  "Incorrect results for input: \"#{string}\""
    end
    %w[101 1000000000001].each do |string|
      expect(binary_multiple_of_4?(string)).not_to be_truthy,  "Incorrect results for input: \"#{string}\""
    end
  end
  it 'rejects invalid binary numbers [10 points]' , points: 10 do
    expect(binary_multiple_of_4?('a100')).to be_falsy, "'a100' is not a valid binary number!"
    expect(binary_multiple_of_4?('')).to be_falsy, 'The empty string is not a valid binary number!'
  end
end
```

Why would `s.chars.all?(/[01]/)`and `arr.all?(Integer)` lead to an ArgumentError in some environments but not others? The documentation isn't giving any answers. More importantly, how can I fix that?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Rather than posting the raw rspec output you should post the source code for the three failing specs, the source code for the methods being tested, and the output + stack trace for the failures. You can print the backtrace with `rspec --backtrace`.

Comment: It might be a ruby version issue. Normally you pass a block to `all?` e.g. `arr.all? { |el| el.is_a?(Array) }` or `arr.all? { |el| el =~ /[01]/ }`. Possibly the shorthand versions you're using are supported with some ruby versions and not others. I'd recommend using the block versions I mentioned. You can try running `ruby -v` locally and on Cloud 9 to see the difference.

Comment: @anothermh - I've added those except for the output + stack trace. In cloud9, I can't select the terminal text formatted as lines, so it's a (long) mess. Once I figure out how to get it formatted, I'll add it.

Comment: @max-pleaner: this just might be it. It was version 2.5.3 local, 2.4.1 in the cloud. The docs for all? for 2.4.1 show only blocks as arguments. Maybe write this as an answer?

Update: this was it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument signatures

```
arr.all?(Integer)
arr.all?(/[01]/)
```

are only supported in Ruby 2.5. You can see this blog post which discusses it

https://blog.bigbinary.com/2018/01/02/ruby-2-5-enumerable-predicates-accept-pattern-argument.html

In older versions of Ruby you must pass a block to `all?`, e.g.:

```
arr.all? { |el| el.is_a?(Integer) }
arr.all? { |el| el =~ /[01]/ }
```

From your comment it seems that your local Ruby environment and cloud 9 are running different versions.